# Redirect to custom error page using global asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have an Application Error method which at the moment redirects the user to a single Action which returns one view. Now this is great and all, however I would like to redirect the user based on the error code returned from the global asax and then display different views. Although I'm not sure how to pass the error code to the controller.

At the moment I have this:

Global asax:

```
  void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Exception TheError = Server.GetLastError();
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            // Avoid IIS7 getting in the middle
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

            if (TheError is HttpException && ((HttpException)TheError).GetHttpCode() == 404) {
                Response.Redirect("~/Error", true);
            }
            else if (TheError is HttpException && ((HttpException)TheError).GetHttpCode() == 500) {
                Response.Redirect("~/Error", true);
            }
            else {
                Response.Redirect("~/Error", true);
            }
```

Controller:

```
 public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Error
        public ActionResult NotFound()
        {
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult ServerError() {
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult UserTimeOut() {
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

But I'd just like to redirect to the Error controller with route values including the error code.

If you need anymore details, just let me know.

Comment: Are you purposefully not using web.config? What other route values besides the error code do you need to specify? You know the error code when you specify to which route to go. Why can't you just append the error code into your literal string that represents your route?

Comment: I had previously used the web config, but for some reason It wouldnt pick my errors up on the server and just left me with the yellow screen of death. I only need the error code, I suppose I could also use the action and redirect to a different action.

Comment: Well, you could put the error code as part of the route data, but that seems fairly hackish. Technically, the StatusCode should be set on the `Request` object when it reaches your controller. I'd recommend giving the web.config another shot at this as it seems like the best place to configure how errors are handled. There are a lot of articles on SO that go into a lot of depth on how to do that - I'll try to find one and link it.

Comment: Thank you, I think i've solved the problem. Although I do agree, web config is better and I think this is a solution until I get more time to look into the web config

Comment: Here's a pastebin of one of our sites httpErrors configured through web.config: http://pastebin.com/NG5SMXrU. Good luck. I know this stuff can be tricky. I seem to have misplaced the link to a great article on it I had.

Comment: @crush Cheers brotha